# Associative group in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, associations

After preprocessing i have a final dataframe with columns 'timestamp', 'group', 'person1', 'person2'. I am trying to figure out how to code my requirement or want to know is it possible using python.
What I am trying to extract is groups within each group. for example: in group G0, A is meeting with B, B meets with C, A meets with D. It means ABCD forms a group within the group. There can be multiple groups within each group (for example in group G1). How can I do this? what logic or code can I apply to extract this? I searched a lot, but it was not of any help..

The pic of dataframe sample and expected output is:
[image]

sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": ['25-06-2020 09:29','25-06-2020 09:29','25-06-2020 09:31','25-06-2020 09:32','25-06-2020 09:33','25-06-2020 09:33','25-06-2020 11:17','25-06-2020 11:17','25-06-2020 11:17','25-06-2020 11:17','25-06-2020 12:29','25-06-2020 12:29','25-06-2020 12:30','25-06-2020 12:30'],
        "group": ['G0','G0','G0','G0','G0','G0','G1','G1','G1','G1','G1','G2','G2','G2'],
        "person1": ['A','A','B','A','X','Z','A','B','L','X','Y','L','N','O'],
        "person2": ['B','B','C','D','Y','N','B','C','M','Y','Z','M','O','P']
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the networkx library [graph theory and connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)):

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": ['25-06-2020 09:29','25-06-2020 09:29','25-06-2020 09:31','25-06-2020 09:32','25-06-2020 09:33','25-06-2020 09:33','25-06-2020 11:17','25-06-2020 11:17','25-06-2020 11:17','25-06-2020 11:17','25-06-2020 12:29','25-06-2020 12:29','25-06-2020 12:30','25-06-2020 12:30'],
        "group": ['G0','G0','G0','G0','G0','G0','G1','G1','G1','G1','G1','G2','G2','G2'],
        "person1": ['A','A','B','A','X','Z','A','B','L','X','Y','L','N','O'],
        "person2": ['B','B','C','D','Y','N','B','C','M','Y','Z','M','O','P']
    }
)

def f(x):
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(x, 'person1', 'person2')
    l = x.apply(lambda n: ''.join(nx.node_connected_component(G, n['person1'])), axis=1)
    return l

df['subgroup'] = df.groupby('group').apply(f).to_numpy()
df
```

Output:

```
           timestamp group person1 person2 subgroup
0   25-06-2020 09:29    G0       A       B     DACB
1   25-06-2020 09:29    G0       A       B     DACB
2   25-06-2020 09:31    G0       B       C     DACB
3   25-06-2020 09:32    G0       A       D     DACB
4   25-06-2020 09:33    G0       X       Y       YX
5   25-06-2020 09:33    G0       Z       N       NZ
6   25-06-2020 11:17    G1       A       B      ACB
7   25-06-2020 11:17    G1       B       C      ACB
8   25-06-2020 11:17    G1       L       M       ML
9   25-06-2020 11:17    G1       X       Y      ZYX
10  25-06-2020 12:29    G1       Y       Z      ZYX
11  25-06-2020 12:29    G2       L       M       ML
12  25-06-2020 12:30    G2       N       O      ONP
13  25-06-2020 12:30    G2       O       P      ONP
```

Groupby subgroups:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df.groupby('subgroup')['timestamp'].agg(['min', 'max'])
```

Output:

```
                         min                 max
subgroup                                        
ACB      2020-06-25 11:17:00 2020-06-25 11:17:00
DACB     2020-06-25 09:29:00 2020-06-25 09:32:00
ML       2020-06-25 11:17:00 2020-06-25 12:29:00
NZ       2020-06-25 09:33:00 2020-06-25 09:33:00
ONP      2020-06-25 12:30:00 2020-06-25 12:30:00
YX       2020-06-25 09:33:00 2020-06-25 09:33:00
ZYX      2020-06-25 11:17:00 2020-06-25 12:29:00
```

Answer (score 1):

This certainly is interesting stuff, especially given the current pandemic. It sounds like you need [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) to help you. Python can do this through dictionaries and custom classes as [this tutorial describes](https://www.python-course.eu/graphs_python.php)

Additionally, [this out-of-date Python documentation](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/) is probably of some help too. You would need to tweak their `find_all_graphs()` function for your requirements.

Comment: yes.. actually the current use case IS about pandemic :) but i should give output in 2 days.. anyways i will go through this :) thanks a lot